# PHP Salvar dados de form em array e exibir em outra página

Tags: php

Boa Tarde.

Estou tentando criar um form cujos dados serão armazenados em um array e devem ser exibidos em outra página quando o cadastro das pessoas for finalizado. Estou tentando fazer isso com SESSION, porém, acredito que não estou conseguindo passar os dados do form para o vetor. Na página de exibição não são exibidos os dados.

Minha página 1:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $aluno =  array();
    $_SESSION['cadastro'] = $aluno;
?>

<form action="cadastroS.php"method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome Completo"></br>
    <input type="number" name="ra" placeholder="RA"></br>
    <select name="gender">
       <option value="Masculino">
       <option value="Feminino">
       <option value="Outro">
    </select></br>
    <input type="number" name="idade"  min="1" max="99"  placeholder="Idade"></br>
    <input type="text" name="endereco" placeholder="Endereço"></br>
    <input type="tel" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone"></br>
    <input type="email" name="email"    placeholder="email"></br></br>
    <input type="submit" name="cadastrar" value="Cadastrar">
</form>

  <?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['cadastro'])){
        array_push(
              $_SESSION['cadastro'],  
              $_REQUEST['nome'],
              $_REQUEST["ra"],
              $_REQUEST["gender"],
              $_REQUEST["idade"],
              $_REQUEST["endereco"],
              $_REQUEST["telefone"],
              $_REQUEST["email"]
        );
    }
  ?>
```

página 2(exibir pessoas cadastradas):

```
<?php
session_start();
    foreach ($_SESSION['cadastro'] as $key => $value) {
        echo $key .':' . $value, '<br>';
    }
?>
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Você está iniciando a sessão onde você armazena os dados em $_SESSION ?

Comment: Sim. Em ambas as páginas estou declarando  "session_start();"

Comment: Faça um teste assim: var_dump($_REQUEST) antes de tentar salvar na array da $_SESSION e verifique se está recebendo os dados, e se recebeu, depois tente: $_SESSION['cadastro']['nome'] = $_REQUEST['nome'] e veja se esse campo passou a ter esse valor na página 2

Comment: Esse teste do var_dump foi na página 'cadastroS.php' com o var_dump($_REQUEST), é isso ? OBS: o arquivo que garda na sessão, é cadastroS mesmo o nome ? com S maiusculo ?

Comment: Fiz as verificações e, com os comandos que vc passou e agora está exibindo os dados na página 2, porém exibe apenas a última inserção de dados. Tentei usar             array_push($_SESSION['cadastro'],  $_REQUEST['nome'], ... $_REQUEST["email"]); para adicionar novos cadastros, mas retorna so o ultimo.

Comment: Você quer que ele armazene na sessão um diferente toda vez que enviar o formulário e fique armazenando todos que forem enviados?

Comment: Todos que forem cadastrados devem ser exibidos de uma vez depois.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supondo que ja enviou o formulário e recebeu do outro lado as informações:

Inicie a sessão novamente:

```
session_start();
```

E logo abaixo faça um leve trabalho com as arrays pra poder permanecer armazenando as informações:

```
$_SESSION['cadastro'] = [];
$cads = count($_SESSION['cadastro']);

if($cads == 0){
    $_SESSION['cadastro'][0] = $_REQUEST;
}else{
    $new_cad = $cads + 1;
    $_SESSION['cadastro'][$new_cad] = $_REQUEST;
}
```

Veja um exemplo funcional no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/xOChH6)

E para exibir na página 2, é necessário uma pequena mudança, pois `$key` deixará de ser o nome do campo:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cadastro'] as $key => $values) {
    echo $key . ':';
    foreach($values as $key_value => $value){
         echo $key_$value . ':' . $value . '<br>';
    }
}
```